# Sorting a list of time string ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following list which I need to sort in ascending order:

```
tlist = ['10:10 AM - 10:20 AM', '10:20 AM - 10:30 AM', '10:30 AM - 10:40 AM', '10:40 AM - 10:50 AM', '10:50 AM - 11:00 AM', '11:00 AM - 11:10 AM', '11:10 AM - 11:20 AM', '11:20 AM - 11:30 AM', '11:30 AM - 11:40 AM', '11:40 AM - 11:50 AM', '11:50 AM - 12:00 PM', '12:00 PM - 12:10 PM', '12:10 PM - 12:20 PM', '12:20 PM - 12:30 PM', '12:30 PM - 12:40 PM', '12:40 PM - 12:50 PM', '12:50 PM - 1:00 PM', '1:00 PM - 1:10 PM', '1:10 PM - 1:20 PM', '1:20 PM - 1:30 PM', '1:30 PM - 1:40 PM', '1:40 PM - 1:50 PM', '1:50 PM - 2:00 PM', '2:00 PM - 2:10 PM', '2:10 PM - 2:20 PM', '2:20 PM - 2:30 PM', '2:30 PM - 2:40 PM', '2:40 PM - 2:50 PM', '2:50 PM - 3:00 PM', '3:00 PM - 3:10 PM', '3:10 PM - 3:20 PM', '3:20 PM - 3:30 PM', '3:30 PM - 3:40 PM', '3:40 PM - 3:50 PM', '3:50 PM - 4:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 4:10 PM', '4:10 PM - 4:20 PM', '4:20 PM - 4:30 PM', '4:30 PM - 4:40 PM', '4:40 PM - 4:50 PM', '4:50 PM - 5:00 PM', '5:00 PM - 5:10 PM', '5:10 PM - 5:20 PM', '5:20 PM - 5:30 PM', '5:30 PM - 5:40 PM', '5:40 PM - 5:50 PM', '5:50 PM - 6:00 PM', '6:00 PM - 6:10 PM', '6:10 PM - 6:20 PM', '6:20 PM - 6:30 PM', '6:30 PM - 6:40 PM', '6:40 PM - 6:50 PM', '6:50 PM - 7:00 PM', '7:00 PM - 7:10 PM', '7:10 AM - 7:20 AM', '7:10 PM - 7:20 PM', '7:20 AM - 7:30 AM', '7:20 PM - 7:30 PM', '7:30 AM - 7:40 AM', '7:30 PM - 7:40 PM', '7:40 AM - 7:50 AM', '7:40 PM - 7:50 PM', '7:50 AM - 8:00 AM', '7:50 PM - 8:00 PM', '8:00 AM - 8:10 AM', '8:00 PM - 8:10 PM', '8:10 AM - 8:20 AM', '8:10 PM - 8:20 PM', '8:20 AM - 8:30 AM', '8:20 PM - 8:30 PM', '8:30 AM - 8:40 AM', '8:30 PM - 8:40 PM', '8:40 AM - 8:50 AM', '8:40 PM - 8:50 PM', '8:50 AM - 9:00 AM', '8:50 PM - 9:00 PM', '9:00 AM - 9:10 AM', '9:00 PM - 9:10 PM', '9:10 AM - 9:20 AM', '9:10 PM - 9:20 PM', '9:20 AM - 9:30 AM', '9:20 PM - 9:30 PM', '9:30 AM - 9:40 AM', '9:40 AM - 9:50 AM', '9:50 AM - 10:00 AM']
```

While attempting to do that, I had written an iterator to list each time string as a time object, but failing in conversion.

```
import time
tlist = ['10:10 AM - 10:20 AM', '10:20 AM - 10:30 AM', '10:30 AM - 10:40 AM', '10:40 AM - 10:50 AM', '10:50 AM - 11:00 AM', '11:00 AM - 11:10 AM', '11:10 AM - 11:20 AM', '11:20 AM - 11:30 AM', '11:30 AM - 11:40 AM', '11:40 AM - 11:50 AM', '11:50 AM - 12:00 PM', '12:00 PM - 12:10 PM', '12:10 PM - 12:20 PM', '12:20 PM - 12:30 PM', '12:30 PM - 12:40 PM', '12:40 PM - 12:50 PM', '12:50 PM - 1:00 PM', '1:00 PM - 1:10 PM', '1:10 PM - 1:20 PM', '1:20 PM - 1:30 PM', '1:30 PM - 1:40 PM', '1:40 PM - 1:50 PM', '1:50 PM - 2:00 PM', '2:00 PM - 2:10 PM', '2:10 PM - 2:20 PM', '2:20 PM - 2:30 PM', '2:30 PM - 2:40 PM', '2:40 PM - 2:50 PM', '2:50 PM - 3:00 PM', '3:00 PM - 3:10 PM', '3:10 PM - 3:20 PM', '3:20 PM - 3:30 PM', '3:30 PM - 3:40 PM', '3:40 PM - 3:50 PM', '3:50 PM - 4:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 4:10 PM', '4:10 PM - 4:20 PM', '4:20 PM - 4:30 PM', '4:30 PM - 4:40 PM', '4:40 PM - 4:50 PM', '4:50 PM - 5:00 PM', '5:00 PM - 5:10 PM', '5:10 PM - 5:20 PM', '5:20 PM - 5:30 PM', '5:30 PM - 5:40 PM', '5:40 PM - 5:50 PM', '5:50 PM - 6:00 PM', '6:00 PM - 6:10 PM', '6:10 PM - 6:20 PM', '6:20 PM - 6:30 PM', '6:30 PM - 6:40 PM', '6:40 PM - 6:50 PM', '6:50 PM - 7:00 PM', '7:00 PM - 7:10 PM', '7:10 AM - 7:20 AM', '7:10 PM - 7:20 PM', '7:20 AM - 7:30 AM', '7:20 PM - 7:30 PM', '7:30 AM - 7:40 AM', '7:30 PM - 7:40 PM', '7:40 AM - 7:50 AM', '7:40 PM - 7:50 PM', '7:50 AM - 8:00 AM', '7:50 PM - 8:00 PM', '8:00 AM - 8:10 AM', '8:00 PM - 8:10 PM', '8:10 AM - 8:20 AM', '8:10 PM - 8:20 PM', '8:20 AM - 8:30 AM', '8:20 PM - 8:30 PM', '8:30 AM - 8:40 AM', '8:30 PM - 8:40 PM', '8:40 AM - 8:50 AM', '8:40 PM - 8:50 PM', '8:50 AM - 9:00 AM', '8:50 PM - 9:00 PM', '9:00 AM - 9:10 AM', '9:00 PM - 9:10 PM', '9:10 AM - 9:20 AM', '9:10 PM - 9:20 PM', '9:20 AM - 9:30 AM', '9:20 PM - 9:30 PM', '9:30 AM - 9:40 AM', '9:40 AM - 9:50 AM', '9:50 AM - 10:00 AM']

for t in tlist:
    f = t.split('-')[0]
    print(f)
    ft = time.strptime(f, "%I:%M %p")
    print(f, ft)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-19-0a2d8195df22> in <module>()
        4     f = t.split('-')[0]
        5     print(f)
  ----> 6     ft = time.strptime(f, "%I:%M %p")
        7     print(f, ft)

  /usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime_time(data_string, format)
      557     """Return a time struct based on the input string and the
      558     format string."""
  --> 559     tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
      560     return time.struct_time(tt[:time._STRUCT_TM_ITEMS])
      561 

  /usr/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
      363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
      364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
  --> 365                           data_string[found.end():])
      366 
      367     iso_year = year = None

  ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

How can I fix this error? Is there an easier technique of sorting these other than the tedious method of looping over the list and transferring to an intermediary list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
f = t.split('-')[0]
ft = time.strptime(f, "%I:%M %p")
```

you end up with a space before and after each date string (eg `'10:10 AM - 10:20 AM'` becomes `'10:10 AM '` and `' 10:20 AM'`).

This is also what the error message is saying:

`ValueError: unconverted data remains:`

`strptime` tried to apply the format `%I:%M %p` to `f`, but it got a leftover whitespace it did not know what to do with.

The solution is to either

split on `' - '`: `f = t.split(' - ')[0]`

or

use `strip` (`f = t.split('-')[0].strip()`) (probably the better solution as it is a bit more generic)

You could also include the whitespace into the format (`time.strptime(f, "%I:%M %p ")`) but this will be a de-facto fix just waiting to break again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
f = t.split('-')[0]
```

To

```
f = t.split('-')[0].strip()
```

After `split('-')`, you will get 2 value exp: '10:10 AM ' and ' 10:20 AM'. So, It need to remove space in these value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sorted`

**Ex:**

```
import time
tlist = ['10:10 AM - 10:20 AM', '10:20 AM - 10:30 AM', '10:30 AM - 10:40 AM', '10:40 AM - 10:50 AM', '10:50 AM - 11:00 AM', '11:00 AM - 11:10 AM', '11:10 AM - 11:20 AM', '11:20 AM - 11:30 AM', '11:30 AM - 11:40 AM', '11:40 AM - 11:50 AM', '11:50 AM - 12:00 PM', '12:00 PM - 12:10 PM', '12:10 PM - 12:20 PM', '12:20 PM - 12:30 PM', '12:30 PM - 12:40 PM', '12:40 PM - 12:50 PM', '12:50 PM - 1:00 PM', '1:00 PM - 1:10 PM', '1:10 PM - 1:20 PM', '1:20 PM - 1:30 PM', '1:30 PM - 1:40 PM', '1:40 PM - 1:50 PM', '1:50 PM - 2:00 PM', '2:00 PM - 2:10 PM', '2:10 PM - 2:20 PM', '2:20 PM - 2:30 PM', '2:30 PM - 2:40 PM', '2:40 PM - 2:50 PM', '2:50 PM - 3:00 PM', '3:00 PM - 3:10 PM', '3:10 PM - 3:20 PM', '3:20 PM - 3:30 PM', '3:30 PM - 3:40 PM', '3:40 PM - 3:50 PM', '3:50 PM - 4:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 4:10 PM', '4:10 PM - 4:20 PM', '4:20 PM - 4:30 PM', '4:30 PM - 4:40 PM', '4:40 PM - 4:50 PM', '4:50 PM - 5:00 PM', '5:00 PM - 5:10 PM', '5:10 PM - 5:20 PM', '5:20 PM - 5:30 PM', '5:30 PM - 5:40 PM', '5:40 PM - 5:50 PM', '5:50 PM - 6:00 PM', '6:00 PM - 6:10 PM', '6:10 PM - 6:20 PM', '6:20 PM - 6:30 PM', '6:30 PM - 6:40 PM', '6:40 PM - 6:50 PM', '6:50 PM - 7:00 PM', '7:00 PM - 7:10 PM', '7:10 AM - 7:20 AM', '7:10 PM - 7:20 PM', '7:20 AM - 7:30 AM', '7:20 PM - 7:30 PM', '7:30 AM - 7:40 AM', '7:30 PM - 7:40 PM', '7:40 AM - 7:50 AM', '7:40 PM - 7:50 PM', '7:50 AM - 8:00 AM', '7:50 PM - 8:00 PM', '8:00 AM - 8:10 AM', '8:00 PM - 8:10 PM', '8:10 AM - 8:20 AM', '8:10 PM - 8:20 PM', '8:20 AM - 8:30 AM', '8:20 PM - 8:30 PM', '8:30 AM - 8:40 AM', '8:30 PM - 8:40 PM', '8:40 AM - 8:50 AM', '8:40 PM - 8:50 PM', '8:50 AM - 9:00 AM', '8:50 PM - 9:00 PM', '9:00 AM - 9:10 AM', '9:00 PM - 9:10 PM', '9:10 AM - 9:20 AM', '9:10 PM - 9:20 PM', '9:20 AM - 9:30 AM', '9:20 PM - 9:30 PM', '9:30 AM - 9:40 AM', '9:40 AM - 9:50 AM', '9:50 AM - 10:00 AM']

print(sorted(tlist, key=lambda x: time.strptime(x.split("-")[0].strip(), "%I:%M %p")))
```

**Output:**

```
['7:10 AM - 7:20 AM', '7:20 AM - 7:30 AM', '7:30 AM - 7:40 AM', '7:40 AM - 7:50 AM', '7:50 AM - 8:00 AM', '8:00 AM - 8:10 AM', '8:10 AM - 8:20 AM', '8:20 AM - 8:30 AM', '8:30 AM - 8:40 AM', '8:40 AM - 8:50 AM', '8:50 AM - 9:00 AM', '9:00 AM - 9:10 AM', '9:10 AM - 9:20 AM', '9:20 AM - 9:30 AM', '9:30 AM - 9:40 AM', '9:40 AM - 9:50 AM', '9:50 AM - 10:00 AM', '10:10 AM - 10:20 AM', '10:20 AM - 10:30 AM', '10:30 AM - 10:40 AM', '10:40 AM - 10:50 AM', '10:50 AM - 11:00 AM', '11:00 AM - 11:10 AM', '11:10 AM - 11:20 AM', '11:20 AM - 11:30 AM', '11:30 AM - 11:40 AM', '11:40 AM - 11:50 AM', '11:50 AM - 12:00 PM', '12:00 PM - 12:10 PM', '12:10 PM - 12:20 PM', '12:20 PM - 12:30 PM', '12:30 PM - 12:40 PM', '12:40 PM - 12:50 PM', '12:50 PM - 1:00 PM', '1:00 PM - 1:10 PM', '1:10 PM - 1:20 PM', '1:20 PM - 1:30 PM', '1:30 PM - 1:40 PM', '1:40 PM - 1:50 PM', '1:50 PM - 2:00 PM', '2:00 PM - 2:10 PM', '2:10 PM - 2:20 PM', '2:20 PM - 2:30 PM', '2:30 PM - 2:40 PM', '2:40 PM - 2:50 PM', '2:50 PM - 3:00 PM', '3:00 PM - 3:10 PM', '3:10 PM - 3:20 PM', '3:20 PM - 3:30 PM', '3:30 PM - 3:40 PM', '3:40 PM - 3:50 PM', '3:50 PM - 4:00 PM', '4:00 PM - 4:10 PM', '4:10 PM - 4:20 PM', '4:20 PM - 4:30 PM', '4:30 PM - 4:40 PM', '4:40 PM - 4:50 PM', '4:50 PM - 5:00 PM', '5:00 PM - 5:10 PM', '5:10 PM - 5:20 PM', '5:20 PM - 5:30 PM', '5:30 PM - 5:40 PM', '5:40 PM - 5:50 PM', '5:50 PM - 6:00 PM', '6:00 PM - 6:10 PM', '6:10 PM - 6:20 PM', '6:20 PM - 6:30 PM', '6:30 PM - 6:40 PM', '6:40 PM - 6:50 PM', '6:50 PM - 7:00 PM', '7:00 PM - 7:10 PM', '7:10 PM - 7:20 PM', '7:20 PM - 7:30 PM', '7:30 PM - 7:40 PM', '7:40 PM - 7:50 PM', '7:50 PM - 8:00 PM', '8:00 PM - 8:10 PM', '8:10 PM - 8:20 PM', '8:20 PM - 8:30 PM', '8:30 PM - 8:40 PM', '8:40 PM - 8:50 PM', '8:50 PM - 9:00 PM', '9:00 PM - 9:10 PM', '9:10 PM - 9:20 PM', '9:20 PM - 9:30 PM']
```

Comment: Can you refer me any page where I can learn about lambda in detail?

Comment: Its pretty simple here. https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/anonymous-function